# Save two selected checkboxes, if i open and close the window (executable example)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

I propose a small executable example of two checkboxes and a button. The goal is to save the selection / check of the combo boxes, in order to close the window and then reopen it to find the selected box. I would like to be able to choose whether to select one or all checkboxes, because I would like to avoid the problem of reloading all checkboxes when I reopen the window, but I want to reload only the selected ones.

I made the connection with Sql creating a table and the value is saved correctly. It is automatically saved 1 in the database, I don't know if it is correct. But if I close and reopen the window, the checkbox is no longer selected.

Can you show me what I can do with a reply? I'm new to Python, if you just leave a comment I might not understand. Thank you

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import messagebox

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.configure(bg='white')

Checkbutton1 = IntVar() 
Checkbutton2 = IntVar() 

#button 1            
Button1 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                      bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white") #command=Button1_func)
Button1.place(x=10, y=36)

#button 2
Button2 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 2", variable = Checkbutton2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                      bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white") #command=Button1_func)
Button2.place(x=10, y=56)
            

def save():
    value_Button1 = Checkbutton1.get()
    value_Button2 = Checkbutton2.get()
                
    if Checkbutton1.get() =="" or Checkbutton2.get() =="":
       tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Select checkbox")

    else:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("...")
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute("UPDATE table_checkbox SET Button1 =? Button=? WHERE id =1;", (value_Button1,), (value_Button2,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("Saved successfully")

             
#Button save
save = Button(root, text="Save", bg='#b40909', foreground='white', command= save)
save.pack()
save.place(x=10, y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

Example Database

```
CREATE TABLE "table_checkbox" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "Button1"   INTEGER,
    "Button2"   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Comment: At which point do you actually read the saved value from the database? You only seem to save it. After creating the checkbox you can set the value that you load from the database.

Comment: @JonathanWeine Yes, I just saved. Not as well as having it "load" from the checkbox when I close and open the window. How can I do? Thank you

Comment: Define a function `load`, that connects to the database as you do in `save` and then execute a `SELECT` Query that gets the checkbox value. Then use the `Checkbutton.set` method to set the value accordingly.

Comment: @JonathanWeine I don't know how i can do it. That's why I asked the question. Can you show me your kind suggestion in an answer? As I also wrote in the question, I am new to Python and with the comments I don't understand much. Thank you

Comment: It's not easy as you'd think, you don't want to UPDATE, you have to initially INSERT, then UPDATE, so you have to use flags and check if the value is inserted before UPDATING those

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Can you show me how to do it in an answer please? Thanks so much

Comment: Nathan you seem to revise your understanding of SQL queries. In both answers your original question was solved, such that if you understand the queries you can generalize this to any amount of GUI elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different things to keep in mind here, first of all is that you don't need to check for the value of `Checkbutton1` and then only insert if it is `""` because it will never be `""`, because it is an integer and never a string.

What you need here is to INSERT the state whatsoever if there is no records already in the table, and if there are records, then UPDATE the records, this is because you ID as PRIMARY KEY.

Ever since you edited the question, you are no longer asking for a case answer, instead a general answer. Here in the example I create `i` checkboxes and at the end I save the `i` values into the database and on reboot, I read those values `i` times and append back to the checkboxes.

The example reads the data from database and updates the items in the list. So what matters is you add each related `IntVar` to the list whenever you create them.

```py
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.configure(bg='white')

chk_lst = []
for i in range(5):
    chk_var = tk.IntVar() 
    tk.Checkbutton(root, text=f"Checkbox {i+1}", variable=chk_var, onvalue=1,
                        offvalue=0, height=1, bg="white", foreground='black',
                        activebackground="white").grid(row=i,column=0)
    chk_lst.append(chk_var)

# CREATE EXTRA CHECKBOXES WITHOUT LOOP
var1 = tk.IntVar()
tk.Checkbutton(root, text=f"Checkbox {i+2}", variable=var1, onvalue=1,
                        offvalue=0, height=1, bg="white", foreground='black',
                        activebackground="white").grid(row=i+1,column=0) #i+1 or whatever row you like
var2 = tk.IntVar()
tk.Checkbutton(root, text=f"Checkbox {i+3}", variable=var2, onvalue=1,
                        offvalue=0, height=1, bg="white", foreground='black',
                        activebackground="white").grid(row=i+2,column=0) 

chk_lst.extend([var1,var2])

def save():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("save.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    
    for idx,chk_btn in enumerate(chk_lst,start=1):
        c.execute(f'SELECT button1 FROM table_checkbox WHERE id=?',(idx,))
        rec = c.fetchall()

        if rec:
            c.execute("UPDATE table_checkbox SET Button1=? WHERE id=?;", (chk_btn.get(),idx))
        else:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO table_checkbox VALUES (?,?);", (idx,chk_btn.get()))
        
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    messagebox.showinfo("Saved successfully","Saved successfully")

def load():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("save.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM table_checkbox")
    vals = c.fetchall()
    
    for val,chk_btn in zip(vals,chk_lst):
        chk_btn.set(val[1])
    
    conn.close()

def create():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("save.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE "table_checkbox" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "Button1"   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT));
    """)
    conn.close()

tk.Button(root, text="Save", bg='#b40909', foreground='white',
                command=save).grid(row=i+1,column=0)

try:
    load()
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    create()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Note: Even if you remove 1 checkbox from the code, it will be stored in the database but it wont be showed in the GUI because I implemented `zip`. So you might want to create a `clean_up` function with `itertools.zip_longest` to delete the extra checkbuttons not in use after GUI closes.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

...
...

def clean_up():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("save.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM table_checkbox")
    vals = c.fetchall()

    for val,chk_box in zip_longest(vals,chk_lst):
        if chk_box is None: # If there is an extra item in the database that is not there in the list, remove the item from the database.
            idx = val[0]
            c.execute('DELETE FROM table_checkbox WHERE id=?',(idx,))
            conn.commit()

    conn.close()

...
...
root.mainloop()
clean_up()
```

Comment: Thank you :) In the same "Save" button do I have to call both the save function and the load function? All I need is the "Save" button, with no other buttons.

Comment: @NathanMüller No, the `load()` function is called at the end before `mainloop()` while loading the application. You can call `load()` anytime after checkbutton has been created.

Comment: Yes, right, you're right. Anyway I'll try your code later. Now I'm going to sleep since it's very late. I'll get back to you later. Thank you. A question: in your example there are errors (due to my code) as the other user who answered my question said?

Comment: @NathanMüller There wont be any errors if you run my code, I believe. I rewrote the function to make sure there wouldn't be any problem despite the checkbutton is ticked or not,

Comment: There is a problem in your code. I tried to add a second checkbox. If I select and save only one of the two checkboxes, then when I close and reopen the window 2 selected checkboxes will be shown (one should be shown instead). Basically, if I understand correctly, your code loads all checkboxes and does not allow you to choose. In the question I asked for a single checkbox for example purposes, but obviously with the idea of implementing the code with other checkboxes. I changed the question and my code, could you change your answer for multiple checkboxes? Thank you

Comment: @NathanMüller I will change my answer for now, but do not repeat this, you get what you asked in the question, after getting an answer you cannot change the question to suit new needs, you did not mention anything about more than 1 checkbox before.

Comment: Thanks,but I notice that you entered the checkboxes with the "for" for i in range(5) loop.In this way I cannot insert the various checkboxes for the future,because I want to insert them individually,writing the name and position for each combobox as I did in my question. I don't want to set a specific number of checkboxes. Two checkboxes are just an example. Can you show me how to please? Forgive my question: can you change your for i in range(5) in the code and add two checkboxes individually?This way you connect to the checkboxes of my question.Thank you

Comment: @DragomirCro Updated with an example. I wont be updating the answer anymore as I am sure I have posted more code for you to be able to understand and figure out how to do this on your own already, you can ask if you do not understand any part of the code :)

Comment: I created the other question because you didn't answer and didn't know how to solve "for i in range (5)". I have now deleted the question. Thank you for replying. I'm testing your code. I didn't understand how to add def clean_up, because you detached it from the main code. Should I add it under the create function? Also, should clean_up () be called AFTER root.mainloop ()?

Comment: @DragomirCro Yes

Comment: In my code I had created two columns in the table: Button1 and Button2. I see you save everything in one column. A question about your code: considering that obviously I will have to recall the data of the table column (for example if the checkbox of the 2nd row with the id 2 is active, then a function is connected to it), I would like to ask you: The numbers 1 or 0 in the column, will they always stay in the same order with the same id? Because if the order changes, the functions linked to the checkboxes will be lost and confused. I hope I explained myself. Thank you

Comment: @DragomirCro We do not care about the location of the checkbox. You do not need to create two columns, if you create two columns, then you will have to create 30 columns for 30 checkbuttons that's hilariously dumb. You want to just add new records for each checkbutton. The column number or row number does not matter, we use the `IntVar` connected with the checkbutton only.

Comment: Sure yes, you're right. Thank you. explain to me briefly what is the task of these cycles please? In save for idx,chk_btn in enumerate(chk_lst,start=1), in load for val,chk_btn in zip(vals,chk_lst) e in Clean Up for val,chk_box in zip_longest(vals,chk_lst). Rest assured that I will set your answer as a solution with a green tick. First I would like to understand things well. This is an interesting answer for future readers as well. Thank you

Comment: @DragomirCro If you want to understand about `zip_longest()` and `zip()` you can google it. There are plenty of answers already out there. You can slowly debug each line if you want to, explaining lines are difficult. Sorry

Comment: Ok, sorry. Can you at least explain your clean_up function to me better? If I understand, you said that if I remove a checkbox from the code this checkbox will be saved in the db and not shown in the GUI. That's okay with me. It's okay if it stays saved in the db even if I don't use it. So can I avoid writing the clean_up function? I am afraid that using clean_up changes the numbering of the checkbox ids. Because to set a function to a checkbox I will use the id via SELECT and WHERE. Thank you

Comment: @DragomirCro Yes, you can remove it. Remember, no checkbox is being saved ANYWHERE, only the value is being saved.

Comment: You say that only the value is saved. So to link a function to a checkbox, if I write like this is it wrong? cursor.execute('SELECT Button1 FROM table WHERE id = 3..........checkbox2 = cursor.fetchone()........... if checkbox2[0] == "1": code

Comment: @DragomirCro I think that's the scope of a new question, you can always ask a new question and get a more detailed answer to that than here in the comments :)

Comment: Ok, so now I ask a new question using the code you wrote me as an example. If you want you can answer too. Obviously, if the answer is useful, I will vote and set the answer as a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the initialization, saving and loading of the checkbox value, althought the save function (basically took it from your example) causes an error if the checkbox is not selected when `save` is called. But as this is not part of the question I leave it to you to figure it out.

```py
import os
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import messagebox

def init_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("GUI_state.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("create table table_checkbox (id integer, button_value integer, PRIMARY KEY('id' AUTOINCREMENT));")
    c.execute("insert into table_checkbox (button_value) values (0)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def save():
    value_Button1 = Checkbutton1_var.get()
    if Checkbutton1_var.get() == "":
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Select checkbox")
    else:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("GUI_state.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(f"UPDATE table_checkbox SET button_value = {value_Button1} WHERE id=1;")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("Saved successfully")


def load():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("GUI_state.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    button_val = c.execute("SELECT button_value FROM table_checkbox WHERE id=1;")
    button_val = tuple(button_val)[0]
    conn.close()
    return button_val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not os.path.exists("GUI_state.db"):
        init_db()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("200x200")
    root.configure(bg='white')

    value = load()
    Checkbutton1_var = IntVar(value=value)

    Button1 = Checkbutton(root, text="Checkbox 1", variable=Checkbutton1_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                          height=1,
                          bg="white", foreground='black',
                          activebackground="white")
    Button1.place(x=10, y=36)

    # Button save
    save = Button(root, text="Save", bg='#b40909', foreground='white', command=save)
    save.pack()
    save.place(x=10, y=80)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In the same "Save" button do I have to recall the three functions you showed me? All I need is the "Save" button, with no other buttons. Thank you.

Comment: Now I'm going to sleep since it's very late. I'll get back to you later. In the meantime, let me know about the button. Thank you

Comment: In case you want to answer, here is the link. I only suggest it because I used your code. If you don't feel like answering, don't worry. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70821194/call-and-assign-functions-to-checkboxes-when-active-status-is-saved-in-a-databa